# How to set gradient color for a SVG element as background image?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, linear-gradients, inline-styles

Hello I'm trying to set gradient color for a SVG element as background image in React

```
style={{ background: `linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow), url(${Background})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}
```

but it applies SVG and linear gradient separately

How can I make the gradient applies to the SVG background ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using SVG as Mask Image

```
style={{ background: `linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow)`, webkitMaskImage: `url(${Background})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the SVG properties to achieve the desired result. SVG provides different inline gradient types. Please check the link: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp